# SSD does not fit exactly

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I'm trying to upgrade a friend's laptop with a SSD. But the SSD doesn't fit exactly into the slot as there are two plastic thingies in the way (marked blue in the following picture). [image: SSD not fitting]

As you can see in the picture you can see there's a small gap where you can see the pins of the SSD. This wasn't the case with the old hard drive as it's case had two small openings. On the other side of the SSD is a screw to keep it in place (not in the picture).

The new SSD is recognized and I was able to install a new OS without any problems. But I'm not sure if this could lead to problems in the future (I'm thinking of dust f.e.). So my question is:

Is it okay to leave the SSD like this? Should I try to remove the plastic thingies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plastic spurs are there for traditional 2.5" mount. Presumably to stabilize a vulnerable disk in a mobile chassis (laptop).

If the SSD is anyway loose then I would shave them off with a file or sandpaper (clean up afterwards). If the locking mechanism at the other end of the drive hold its in snugly then its not a problem, SATA prongs are longer than is strictly required.